# Blazor WebAsembly Access Database

Tags: c#, blazor

I am just thinking that, Since Blazor Webassembly can running in browser independently(off-line), how can it access database without a WebAPI?

Can Blazor Webassembly use sqlite in browser directly?

Comment: Can Blazor Webassembly use sqlite in browser directly?

Answer (score 5):

You can use in browser DBs [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), Web SQL or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) throught [JSInteropt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to choose one of them if I can not use sqlite by risking of data been changed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

> How can it access database without a WebAPI?

It can't access any database without a Web Api. You can only access the JavaScript localStorage and sessionStorage Apis, using JSInterop. Right now Blazor does not support such adventures, but I'm not much acquainted with products created by third parties and the community... perhaps they've created something that can be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I agree with you that I can noly access localstorage and indexeddb. Users can edite any data what ever they want, it's a risk for me.

Comment: You can now access local storage from Blazor without JSInterop.  there is a nuget package that is available: Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage.

Answer (score 1):

No Blazor Webassembly can not use sqlite in browser directly.
Blazor Webassembly can running in browser independently(off-line), 
it can access database without a WebAPI but first you have to start creating project by chossing 
Blazor Web assembly project then use ASP.Net Core Hosted and Prograssive Web App selected.
Now you can use database and share logic. And for Off line capability you have to change in worker.js according to your need. 
And You can use in browser DBs IndexedDB, Web SQL or local storage or JSON File